# Chrome and Safari jQuery .click and .css anchor color bug?

Tags: jquery, css

So I tried to put my finger on the cause of this and it started driving me nuts.

This morning I put a jquery scroller for my clients logos in the right sidebar of my website http://followworks.com.

It works perfect in Firefox... Of course!

But Safari and Chrome cut of the first image and the left right buttons don't even work???

Here's the code I have in my .js file

```
var totalSlides = 14;
var currentSlide = 1;
var contentSlides = "";
$(".clientLeftTab").click(showPreviousSlide); 
$(".clientRightTab").click(showNextSlide); 
var totalWidth = 0; 
contentSlides = $(".slideshow-content"); 
contentSlides.each(function(i){
    totalWidth += this.clientWidth; totalSlides++; }); 
    $("#slideshow-holder").width(totalWidth); 
    $("#slideshow-scroller").attr({scrollLeft: 0}); 
    function showPreviousSlide(e) { 
        currentSlide--; updateContentHolder(); 
    } 
    function showNextSlide(e){ 
        currentSlide++; updateContentHolder();
    } 
    function updateContentHolder(e){ 
        var scrollAmount = 0; 
        contentSlides.each(function(i){ 
            if(currentSlide - 1 > i) { scrollAmount += this.clientWidth; } 
        }); 
$("#slideshow-scroller").animate({scrollLeft: scrollAmount}, 300); 
}
```

Also, my other issue is that when users click on links in Chrome and Safari they turn white... I've checked my .css file http://followworks.com/css/new_style.css and theres is no syntax to make a link white for a:active or a:focus? Weirdness... I know someone else has had this problem... easy fix I bet! :-)

Please let me know what's wrong with my .js code.

Comment: It is still having issues? Do you know why the links turn white in Chrome and Safari when they are clicked? Never seen that before???

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `function functionname(args)` with this syntax: `var functionname = function(args)` - this ensures that the functions are being defined in the right closure.

In fact, in this case you want to move the function definition outside of the `each` code, as they will be available inside the `each` while being more memory-efficient.

Comment: Tried what you suggested and it failed?

Comment: nope... it just didn't scroll at all? Crazy it works perfect in Firefox... that's because firefox rules! :)

Comment: Funny thing! I don't what I did... but I fixed it! LOL

Comment: It is still having issues? Do you know why the links turn white in Chrome and Safari when they are clicked? Never seen that before???